# how can i merge phone number validation and formatting number

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code for validation:

```
var isValidPhone = /^\+?[\d- ]{7,15}$/.test(this.val());
```

And I want to have formatting the number at the same place, something like:

```
(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{7})/,'$1-$2'))
```

How can I merge them?

I want the phone to be as 0-xxxxxxxxx and the end.

Comment: You can directly format the number then compare the string containing original number with new number. If the number is changed then it means the regex matched so number is valid if not then regex couldn't be matched so invalid number.

Comment: would you please tell me how the code will be?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

You need to do something like this -

```
var num = "1234567890";
var original = num;//for comparing later
//edited new line :
/^\+?[\d- ]{7,15}$/.test(num) || num.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{7})/, '$1-$2');//checks if num is valid, if not then tries to replace

if(original != num)
{
    //number is in correct format, variable 'num' contains newly formatted number if it wasnt in correct format already
}
else
{
    //number NOT in correct format!
}
```

If the formatted number is not same as original then it will mean that regex got matched and that means number is in correct format. If they are same then it will mean that regex was not matched so number is not in correct format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what I want to do is: if the user put the number as 0xx-xxxxxxx its valid and its working fine now. I want to change the number for the users that put the number as xxxxxxxxxx to the format of  0xx-xxxxxxx